# Resolving mixed open-closed generics with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm trying to resolve a mixed open-closed generic type with constraints using Castle Windsor. This should be able to resolve any open generics if Foo implements IFoo<>:

`container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IFoo<>).ImplementedBy(typeof(Foo<>)));`

My situation is slightly more complex:

I have the following `Handler` class:

```
public abstract class CommandHandlerBase<TCommand, TResponse>
    : IRequestHandler<TCommand, TResponse>
    where TCommand : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    public abstract Task<TResponse> Handle(
        TCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class AddMasterDataEntityCommandHandler<TNewEntityData>
    : IRequestHandler<TNewEntityData, Response>
    where TNewEntityData : IRequest<Response>
{
    public Task<Response> Handle(
        TNewEntityData request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

The idea is that `AddMasterDataEntityCommandHandler` will be a generic command handler that can handle any type of contract of type `TNewEntityData`.

Since I'm using [Mediatr](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR), my contracts have to implement `IRequest<,>`, which they do. In this case, I'm enforcing that all the handlers should return a `Response`.

Example usage:

`Response response = await mediator.Send(new AddMasterDataEntityCommand<NewPlace>());`

I created a simple console app to isolate this behavior:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.Register(Types.FromThisAssembly()
                                .BasedOn(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>))
                                .Unless(t => t.IsAbstract || t.IsInterface)
                                .WithServices(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>))
                                .LifestyleTransient());

        var instance = container.Resolve(typeof(IRequestHandler<NewData, Response>));
    }
```

However, a test throws an exception indicating an error in my code:

> Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.GenericHandlerTypeMismatchException: 'Types ConsoleApp4.NewData, ConsoleApp4.Response don't satisfy generic constraints of implementation type ConsoleApp4.AddMasterDataEntityCommandHandler'1 of component 'ConsoleApp4.AddMasterDataEntityCommandHandler'1'. This is most likely a bug in your code.'

I don't see the issue here, CW should be able to resolve open/closed generics, right? Furthermore, the problem seems to be related to the additional `Response` parameter as a `TResponse` type. Did I register the component the wrong way? I'm confident I didn't mess up the generic constraints...

Thanks in advance to anyone who can take a look.

Comment: It appears that `NewData` does not implement `IRequest<Response>`.

Comment: does it work when you go `new AddMasterDataEntityCommandHandler<NewData>()`?

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt `NewData` does implement `IRequest<Response>`

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic Yes, constructing it manually does work.

Comment: _Complicated_ open generic components are tricky to support so you may have hit an edge case. There's a hook to manually handle that: `IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy` which may help. See this for example: http://kozmic.net/2013/07/24/on-castle-windsor-and-open-generic-component-arity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Krzysztof Kozmic led me into the right direction:

I initially tried an implementation with `IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy` but couldn't get this working to it only being able to handle a type with one generic. I ended up registering like this with a bit of reflection magic:

```
private void RegisterGenericMasterDataCommandHandlers(IWindsorContainer container) {
    foreach (Type contractType in contractTypes) {
        Type requestedType = typeof(IRequestHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(AddMasterDataEntityCommand<>).MakeGenericType(contractType), typeof(Response));
        Type implementedType = typeof(AddMasterDataEntityCommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(contractType);

        container.Register(Component.For(requestedType, implementedType));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you fill in the complete code like what `contractTypes` is...

Comment: I don't have access to this code anymore since I left the company since I posted this question, but I believe `contractTypes` was the list of request types. Basically you can construct the types such as `IRequestHandler<AddMasterDataEntityCommand<SomeEntity>,Response>` at runtime. `SomEntity` is the contractType in this case.